# lastSignInTimestamp is bigger than the current timestamp in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I just implemented Firebase auth. After I sign-up, I want to know much time my users spend in my app. If I try:

```
val t1 = Date(auth.currentUser?.metadata?.lastSignInTimestamp).time
val t2 = Date().time
val result = t2 - t1
print(result) //prints (-3 seconds)
```

Right after createUserWithEmailAndPassword completes, I get a negative value. How can the current timestamp be before the timestamp of an authentication that is completed few seconds earlier? How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamps in the user's `metadata` are generated on the Firebase Authentication server, while `Date().time` generates a timestamp in the place where your code executes. Since these timestamps comes from different machines, there's a chance that there is a (positive or negative) offset between the clocks on these two machines.

If you want to measure this so-called skew, you can capture the local timestamp (`Date().time`) when the user signs in, and compare that with the server timestamp (`auth.currentUser?.metadata?.lastSignInTimestamp`). Since the offset is likely fixed, you can then continue to use this offset in the rest of your application.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I understand now.